# Trying to create a Android Soft Keyboard from an activity

Tags: android, service, keyboard

I wrote a activity for a keyboard.
Now I am moving a class that extends Activity to another that exteds `InputMethodService`...
And I am missing `findViewById` to create the keyboard layout.
Because I have not enough knoledge to create a SoftKeyboard I include the Java code.
My next step will be to modify the AndroidManifest.xml to be a service, I guess.

```
package com.keyboard.mine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends InputMethodService /* Activity */ {
    ...
    ...
//    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//        return true;
//    }


    private void nuevas_teclas (String [][] teclas_array) {
        Button boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button00);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][0]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button01);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][1]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button02);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][2]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button10);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][4]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button11);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][5]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button12);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][6]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button20);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][8]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button21);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][9]);
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button22);
        boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][10]);   
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.button31);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][13].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][13]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux0);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][3].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][3]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux1);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][7].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][7]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux2);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][11].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][11]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux3);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][15].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][15]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux4);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][14].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][14]);
        }
        boton = (Button) ***findViewById***(R.id.buttonaux5);
        if (! teclas_array [pagina][12].equals ("")) {
            boton.setText(teclas_array [pagina][12]);
        }
}
...
... 
...
}
```

Comment: why do you want to create a new one? you can raise the soft keyboard programmatically..

Answer (score 0):

You can check following source codes available :

[Scandinavian-keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/scandinavian-keyboard/source/checkout) 

[Hackers Keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/checkout)

[Android Emoji Keyboard](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard)

And then try to make on your own. 

Hope this helps you and you can get some basic idea.